# Why does coroutine in background execute before the main thread in this Kotlin Coroutines situation?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am a newbie to Kotlin coroutines and trying to understand the coroutine builder `launch` which starts a coroutine in background and does not block the main thread. So I have tested it with a simple example like so.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        delay(1000L)
        println("World!")
    }
    println("Hello!")
    runBlocking {
        delay(2000L) // Testing by modifying this delay time
    }
}
```

To my understading, because there is a 1 second delay in the background coroutine, in the meantime, the `println("Hello!")` in the main thread will be executed immediately first. And then, because we have blocked the main thread using `delay` in `runBlocking` for 2 seconds to keep the JVM alive, the background coroutine should have enough time to execute `println("World!")`.

I have tested this code on [Kotlin Playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/), and have tried changing the delay time in `runBlocking` to smaller values such as `delay(1001L)` or `delay(700L)` which then prints the output:

```
World! Hello!
```

With delay time of 1002ms, it sometimes prints

```
Hello!
World!
```

but sometimes prints

```
World! Hello!
```

Also, I assumed that if the delay time in `runBlocking` is 700ms, then only `Hello!` should be printed.

I understand that with sufficient time of JVM being alive (such as the 2000ms delay case in the first code snippet), the background coroutine has enough time to execute `println("World!")`. However, what is confusing is the fact that sometimes `World!` is printed before `Hello!` and also on the same line. What could be causing this type of behaviour?

Comment: Seems to be a playground bug in combination with coroutines. It seems to swallow every new line character when printed (or assigned) within the launch...

Comment: ... it might only be a problem when using `GlobalScope.launch` .... using `main() = runBlocking { launch { ... } ... runBlocking { ... } }` seems to look good...

Comment: @Roland Yes, it seems to be a bug with the playground because it works fine as expected on IntelliJ IDEA. I have opened an issue on its [github](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-playground/issues/157).